# Gmail Hangouts contact card pops up at the wrong times

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I am using the Hangouts pane in my email on mail.google.com. The issue is that whenever I mouse across the the list of contacts (say when I'm moving my mouse to my other monitor) the contact card opens up.

It will stay open indefinitely unless I mouse over another contact or click somewhere else in the page (there are links everywhere so I can't just click on "white space" easily). Sometimes the contact card opens on a delay too and I click on am email but between me initiating the click on an email with my brain and the mouse button going down the contact card opens and I end up opening someone's contact details.

Is there a way to have these contact cards either not open on hover (on a click instead) or open at a much longer delay (like a 0.5 or 1 second) or auto close after some period of time?